# Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types '()' and 'String?'

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I have no idea what i am getting wrong here, i am basically checking if a value is coming back nil then populate the `UILabel` with a standard number or else if the value comes back, i populate the `UILabel` with the value.

```
account.agent.ddi == "" || account.agent.ddi == nil ? self.ddiLabel.text = "02039909000" : self.ddiLabel.text =  account.agent.ddi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're assigning to `self.ddiLabel.text` in both of the cases you can separate the assignment from the `?:` operation, making the return type `String` in both cases

```
ddiLabel.text = account.agent.number == "" || account.agent.ddi == nil ? "02039909000" : account.agent.ddi
```

Answer (score 1):

It's heavy for the the compiler without `()`

```
account.agent.ddi == "" || account.agent.ddi == nil ? ( self.ddiLabel.text = "02039909000" ) : ( self.ddiLabel.text =  account.agent.ddi)
```